# Converting name months to numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I’m a beginner and I’m having a lot of difficulties to plot my data contained in a csv file given that for this case the name months (which are abbreviated) in the file need to be necessarily converted to numbers. I’ve been told to use the library “time” and I’ve spent so many hours looking for possible solutions but nothing has worked yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could also create a dictionary the Maps month names to a number. And what about using the time library hasn't worked? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Using time Library for seems like an overkill. Easiest way to this would be to create a dictionary. But if you want to achieve this using time library then you can try

```
from time import strptime
strptime('Mar','%b').tm_mon
```

Comment: I tryed this option and also tryed to create a dictionary. Unfortunatelly neither of them worked. Thanks!